# NextJS Routing considers / and %2F in determining the route

Tags: next.js

I have a url like this:
`manage/text_U2FsdGVkX1/7AucFzVPX7OpRHb8Dlk/ApiJsTvYroROv4Ds4oshwC+cg3a7Mz/aO`
Which should be processed by the route/directory `/pages/manage/[id]`

> id = test_someEncryptedString

However due to the `/` this wont work. So I decided to encode this (using `encodeURIComponent`) which gives me this url:
`manage/test_U2FsdGVkX1%2F7AucFzVPX7OpRHb8Dlk%2FApiJsTvYroROv4Ds4oshwC%2Bcg3a7Mz%2FaO`

On my local dev server this works fine, but on production I get a 404.
I guess NextJS still considers `%2F` as a `/` and looks for that route?

Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: Hey @strangeQuirks, did you manage to solve it? Same situation here

Answer (score 0):

If you double encode/decode, it works OK.

```
let yourValue = encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(yourValue))

// Go to your route, for example:
// router.push(`/page/${yourValue}`)
```

On the server side you can then double-decode, like this:

```
let yourValue = decodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(yourValue))
```